# How to skip setup and teardown in unittest case while using pytest and commandline option?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

### Current setup

using

- pytest 3.4.1
- python 3.5 and above

This is my test case under `tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py`

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # do setup stuff here

    def tearDown(self):
        # do teardown stuff here

    def test_case_1(self):
        # test case here...
```

I use `unittest` style to write my test case. I use pytest to run the tests.

I have also setup and teardown functions following `unittest` conventions

My commandline to run the tests become

`pytest -s -v tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py`

It works as expected

### What I want

When I debug sometimes, i want to be able to easily turn off either setup or teardown or both at the same time using some kind of commandline option

`pytest -s -v tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py --skip-updown`

in order to skip both teardown and setup

`pytest -s -v tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py --skip-setup`

in order to skip setup

`pytest -s -v tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py --skip-teardown`

in order to skip teardown

### What I tried and didn't work

#### Tried `sys.argv`

I have tried using `sys.argv`

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        if '--skip-updown' in sys.argv:
            return
        # do setup stuff here
```

and then

`pytest -s -v tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py --skip-updown

This didn't work and my error message is

```
usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: argument --skip-updown: expected one argument
```

#### Tried sys.argv

I have tried using `sys.argv`

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        if '--skip-updown' in sys.argv:
            return
        # do setup stuff here
```

and then

`pytest -s -v tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py --skip-updown`

This didn't work and my error message is

```
usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: argument --skip-updown: expected one argument
```

#### Tried conftest.py and config.getoption

I setup a `conftest.py` in the project root

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--skip-updown", default=False)


@pytest.fixture
def skip_updown(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--skip-updown")
```

And then

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        if pytest.config.getoption("--skip-updown"):
            return
        # do setup stuff here and then
```

`pytest -s -v tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py --skip-updown`

Then I get

```
usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: argument --skip-updown: expected one argument
```

### What I tried and worked but not as ideal

#### Tried conftest and config.getoption but this time declare --skip-updown=True

Exactly the same as before except this time in my command line I declare `--skip-updown=True`

`pytest -s -v tests/test_8_2_openpyxl.py --skip-updown=True`

### My question

This is very close to what I want, but I was hoping not to have to declare the value `--skip-updown=True`

Or maybe I am doing it all wrong in the first place and there's an easier way using `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix `addoption`:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--skip-updown", action='store_true')
```

See the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

> Or maybe I am doing it all wrong in the first place and there's an easier way using sys.argv.

No, what you're doing is the right and the only way.

Comment: oh thanks! I didn't realise that about `store_true`.